# Rails: Removing migrations/schema created by gem on uninstall

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there an easy way to drop tables created by a gem when I am installing it? For my specific case I want to uninstall the gem and reinstall it but the old tables and data are still there. Right now I plan on dropping the created tables manually. Is there a way to see all the tables created by a gem?

Comment: *Is there a way to see all the tables created by a gem?* - How about `git diff commit1..commit2 -- db/schema.rb`?

Comment: nice one, why to go with git diff, normal diff will also work, what you need are two schemas.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Where to get these two files? I assume from git's repo. Hence, it's simpler to use git to get diff instead of extracting two versions and compare them after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to see all the tables created by a gem, unless they're namespaced within something sensible. For example, [Forem](http://github.com/radar/forem) namespaces all the tables with a `forem_` prefix.

You would need to create a migration and drop the tables manually.